# When an incoming call is detected, start the android app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver

I want to detect an incoming call. I did this with a broadcast Receiver, this works fine. But when my App is closed, then it says "App has stopped"(App crashed). So how can I start my App to perform actions?

Here's my BroadcastReceiver:

```html
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class InterceptCall extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "InterceptCall";

    private static MainActivity activity;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: incoming call");

            activity.startCallScreen();
        }
    }

    public static void setActivity (MainActivity mainActivity) {
        activity = mainActivity;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So guys... if found the answer myself :D

Just need to use the Context of the onReceife and do:

```html
context.startActivity(new Intent(context, MainActivity.class));
```